# how to style menu.item on semantic ui React <input> search bar precisely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

The code is the menu style of semantic ui available for React including a search input i want to increase the size of the search input and also change the color.

```
<Menu secondary>
            <Menu.Item>
              <img alt="logo" src={logo} 
               active={activeItem === 'home'}
               onClick={this.handleItemClick}
              />
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item>
                <Input icon='circle outline' iconPosition='left' placeholder='Search...' />
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Menu position='right'>
              
              <Menu.Item
                name='logout'
                active={activeItem === 'logout'}
                onClick={this.handleItemClick}
              />
            </Menu.Menu>
          </Menu>
```

Comment: You can add className to the second Menu Item in which you have the search input, then you have to add a CSS style for it :)

Comment: thank you i ended up doing this using an id tag though.